Second monitor is detected but not working
I have a Ubuntu 22 PC with an NVIDIA GPU. Two monitors are connected and detected:


However, only one monitor works, while the other remains black. The monitors and cables have been already tested on other computers.
I noticed this error in Xorg log:

(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown. [
1702.103] (EE) Failed to load /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/xrdpdev_drv.so:
/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/xrdpdev_drv.so: undefined symbol:
rdpRRModeDestroy [  1702.103] (EE) Failed to load module "xrdpdev"
(loader failed, 0) [  1702.126] (EE) Server terminated with error (2).
Closing log file.

I already tried to edit the grub file like this, without success:
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvidia-drm.modeset=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"

If I try to run sudo X -configure, this is the output:
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Current Operating System: Linux francesco-ufficio 6.8.0-40-generic #40~22.04.3-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jul 30 17:30:19 UTC 2 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic root=UUID=e97f027d-ec8a-4937-a2eb-661d9a3e7c2b ro quiet splash nomodeset vt.handoff=7
xorg-server 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.11 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Aug 20 17:56:12 2024
List of video drivers:
    amdgpu
    ati
    intel
    nouveau
    qxl
    radeon
    vmware
    xrdpdev
    modesetting
    fbdev
    vesa
(++) Using config file: "/root/xorg.conf.new"
(==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.
  Configuration failed.
(EE) Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file.

How can I fix this problem?

Does xrandr detect the monitor?

And FYI nomodeset bypasses the driver. It is NOT to be used in any case other than then a temporary workaround while troubleshooting, i.e., typically to have some sort of low resolution video until you install the proprietary drivers.

@choroba yes it does

If so check Gnome's/your OS' settings, NOT the Nvidia X Server Settings tool. You'll likely find there the second monitor disabled.

As shown in the first picture, the second monitor is visible in the OS settings
